# Sort a huge collection of text files

Tags: bash, loops, file, count, find

I'm trying to sort a huge collection of text files. They are in various folders.
All the files and folders doesn't have spaces in their names.

- The text files names look like: hsXOAXOMQovq.txt (12 random letters and a txt extension)
- The folders names look like: FOLDER_x_y (where x and y are a number from 1 to 5)

My goal is to move them in folders ordered in alphabetic order.

- A -> Folder for files which begin by 'a' or 'A'
- ...
- Z -> Folder for files which begin by 'a' or 'Z'

First, I want to count how many files begin with a 'A' or 'a' and I run successively the command:
`find . -iname 'J*.txt' | wc -l`
It returns the good number of files

Then I write this code:

```
for letter in {A..Z}
do
    cmd1="find . -iname '${letter}*.txt' | wc -l"
    echo $cmd1  # display good command
    nb=$($cmd1) 
    echo -e "$letter:\t$nb files"
done
```

It doesn't work and display this message (for example when $letter equal 'Q':

```
find . -iname 'Q*.txt' | wc -l
find: paths must precede expression: `|'
Q:       files
```

I tried various syntax with or without spaces between the pipe but none of them worked.
When I write these commands out of the for loop, they work well:

```
find . -iname 'J*.txt' | wc -l
find . -iname 'J*.txt'| wc -l
find . -iname 'K*.txt'|wc -l
```

I don't understand what the problem is!

Comment: Variables hold data. Functions hold code. Don't put code inside variables! There are many situations in which people try to shove commands, or command arguments, into variables and then run them. Each case needs to be handled separately.  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do:

```
for letter in {A..Z}
do
    nb=$(find . -iname "${letter}*.txt" | wc -l)
    echo -e "$letter:\t$nb files"
done
```

[image: note]

Variables hold data. Functions hold code. Don't put code inside variables! There are many situations in which people try to shove commands, or command arguments, into variables and then run them. Each case needs to be handled separately. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

---

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> https://web.archive.org/web/20230224010517/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> [when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)